# SCNAction of scenekit only executing action once

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I want objects that I created to "fall" down the view of the controller. I also want an infinite amount of objects to fall, so continuing the animation until the the user goes to another view controller. I used a for-loop to make up to 100 objects. Here is the code...

```
 SCNMaterial *blackMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
blackMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor blackColor];

int xcoordinate = arc4random_uniform(20);
int xcoordinateTwo = arc4random_uniform(20);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

    SCNText *x = [SCNText textWithString:@"X" extrusionDepth: 2.75];
    SCNNode *xNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:x];
    xNode.position = SCNVector3Make(xcoordinate, 15.0, -60.0);
    xNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(2.0, 2.0, 0.45);
    x.materials = @[blackMaterial];
    x.chamferRadius = 5.0;
    SCNAction *moveTo = [SCNAction moveTo:SCNVector3Make(xcoordinate, -100.0, -60.0)duration:10.0];
    [xNode runAction:moveTo];

    SCNTorus * torus = [SCNTorus torusWithRingRadius:6.30 pipeRadius:2.30];
    SCNNode *torusNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:torus];
    torusNode.position = SCNVector3Make(xcoordinateTwo, 15.0, -60.0);
    torus.materials = @[blackMaterial];
    torusNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-1.5708, 0, 0);
    [torusNode runAction:moveTo];


    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:torusNode];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:xNode];

}
```

The problem for me is that only one of each object is being created instead of a 100. Can I anyone help me with what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are creating 100 of each object:

```
NSLog(@"%@", scene.rootNode.childNodes);
```

They all have the same origin and destination positions because your calls to `arc4random_uniform` are outside the loop. They're all in the same place so it looks like just one node.

Moving the random number calls inside will disperse your nodes but they'll all be created at the same simulation time. To generate them continuously, you can construct an `[SCNAction sequence:[...]]` with an array of actions: a block action to create a new node and add it to the tree, followed by a delay action. Wrap that in a `repeatActionForever:` and make your root node perform that action. You'll also want to remove nodes when they reach destination or go out of view.

Comment: Thank you,  could you possibly post an example as well

Comment: @Harshil.Chokshi Well I'm not going to write the whole thing for you. But if you can articulate the points you don't understand, I'll try to clarify. You should begin by rereading the reference documentation for each of the classes and methods I mentioned.

Comment: PS: you've asked several SceneKit questions that have received solid answers, but you haven't responded. Please acknowledge that help by accepting the correct answers. That closes the question and gives a bump to the people who helped you.

Comment: Thank you I got it. Sorry about that will provide better feedback